# Recommend an open source CMS for single page web site

Tags: php, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

Hi I want to create a single page web site like http://kiskolabs.com/ or http://www.carat.se to display my portfolio.  I want to add new products after launching the site without having to edit the entire site.

I've looked at opencart (too much for single page site), Magneto (more for ecommerce), Wordpress (couldn't find open source / free templates which i can start from).

Can you suggest a CMS which will support the creation of a single page site and allow insertion of new products without having to edit the entire page? I would prefer a CMS which also has open source / free templates which I can tweak for my use.

I can do php and mysql, xml.

If it is an easier option I can do PSD to site (but don't know much about this at all).

Comment: You don't need a CMS for just that, just a single html file would do (with content loaded in AJAX); someone will suggest wordpress, but beware! you'll have a ton of feature useless for you; a database (for dynamically add content) and a single php/html file imho are the best; pick a site layout you like from anywhere and take inspiration from it

Comment: Wow thanks guys i'm very pleased to see so many people giving answers on some things i didnt even new exist!

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14792/which-tiny-open-source-cms-for-a-single-page-website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various options available.

There are numerous well known options including Joomla, Drupal, PyroCMS etc but all of which are likely overkill for a single page.

I actually really like [Perch](http://grabaperch.com/) for single page sites as it's lightweight and easy to use.

Have you looked at [Craig Russell's Single CMS](https://github.com/craig552uk/SingleCMS) designed exactly for this purpose?

Another option is [Cushy CMS](http://www.cushycms.com/en) although it's hosted.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985396/a-cms-for-a-one-page-site) here on SO may also provide some suggestions.

Comment: Your link to Craig's [Single CMS](http://craig-russell.co.uk/2011/09/20/single-cms-the-one-page-cms.html#.UOc-waUdqS0) is broken, and it seems it's the only free one :(

Comment: It moved to github. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Free CMS-es for a single page: [Cosmo CMS](http://www.cosmocms.org/), [Couch CMS](http://www.couchcms.com/), [Wonder CMS](http://wondercms.com).

Answer (score 1):

using an existing CMS is overkill. a ton of features, library loading and SQL fetching just to show a single paged website. if i were to choose, i'd have a static single paged website!

however, if you're going on the CMS route, i personally use [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) due to ease of use (for me at least). the extension directory is their bullet of victory housing a ton of extensions. But for custom built extensions - rare and seldom updated documentation  kills you.

[WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) is the way to go for portfolio+blog websites also. they are used by almost all people i see on the internet. pretty flashy that i am also tempted to learn wordpress.

i also heard that the [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) framework is very fast. There are CMS built from CI like [PyroCMS](http://www.pyrocms.com/), [Halogy](http://www.halogy.com/), and [FUEL](http://www.getfuelcms.com/). give them a shot.

but still, single page?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your problem might be to start with a high quality theme such as those found on [Theme Forrest](http://themeforest.net/), then either adopt the CMS the theme was designed for, or gut it out and write your own simple CMS just for the product area of the page.  As Damien Pirsy says in his comment, most CMS's will probably be overkill for this job, and building your own will probably only take a couple of hours.

Comment: IMO, it makes more sense to spend 5 minutes to install WP than several hours to write your own CMS. WP will at least come with good templating, SEO, and a bunch of other features that you don't notice (until they're gone) that make it easier to run a successful site. And it'll be able to accommodate future growth. A CMS you write in a day will be really rough and much more likely to be buggy and insecure. It would be better to just build a static page in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I like CMS Made Simple http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/, it´s very lightweight.

You have some Picture Album modules, some open source themes and some e-commerce modules that can be installed as you need, for example, only a Cart module.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is a static site then simply use HTML and CSS.

If your site is dynamic one, i.e needs to make connection with database. Then use [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/)

As if database connection then the site is more vulnerable to hacking. Moreover wordpress is easy to handle and more secure